# How to highlight a row in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4

In a `UITableView` (with cells loaded a XIB file) I'm trying to detect which label is clicked in a table cell so can I can push different view controllers in.  So if the user clicks the clientname label they will get the clientdetails viewcontroller or clientpostcode brings up a mapsviewcontroller.

The code I have to attach a uitapgesture to the labels works fine, but the didselecrowatindex does not get called and the row is not highlighted.  I will like to highlight the row as well.

(in cellforrowatindexpath)

```
label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture =
    [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
        action:@selector(labelTap)] autorelease];
[label addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

I have check a lot of apple's examples where they put buttons on rows but even their examples don't highlight the row either.

So in summary can I work out which label is selected AND highlight the row?

thanks in advance, please ask for any clarification this was difficult to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Detect the row of the label and use this tableView method to highlight it,

```
- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
                    animated:(BOOL)animated 
              scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition
```

**Row detection:**

To locate the point from gesture, 
You can use,

```
- (CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView *)view
```

And then detect the row,

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRowAtPoint:(CGPoint)point
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply... where / how should I detect the row of the label?

Comment: some hints in the answer is given.